# Normalization a table

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I want to normalize this table to 3NF

```
              -----------------------------------
              |        |         |              |
              |        V         V              V
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|user_name|post_id|post_title|post_text|post_submitted_time|comment_id|comment_text|submited_comment_time|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |        |                                                  ^            ^                ^
     |        |                                                  |            |                |
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How I can do this Work?

Comment: What are the relations between user, post and comment?

Comment: I want to store my website post's and all comment of about these post's. should save who submited post(username) and who submited comment(username) about a post(post_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming user_name is a PK.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|post_id|post_title|post_text|post_submitted_time|user_name|
------------------------------------------------------------
     1      foo       bar          08:15             baz  

------------------------------------------------------------------
|comment_id|comment_text|submitted_comment_time|user_name|post_id|
------------------------------------------------------------------
     1         blabla          13:37             anyname     1
     2         foobar          13:38             anyname     1
```

Comment: Use the <pre> html tag and type away.

Comment: IMO the table 'post_id|comment_id' is not really needed, because you don't have a many to many relationship here. rather have the post_id in the comment-table like in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Split it up to three tables, that's the whole magic.

User:

- ID (PK)
- Name

Post:

- ID (PK)
- Title
- Text
- Submitted_Time
- UserID (FK)

Comment:

- ID (PK)
- Text
- UserID (FK)
- PostID (FK)

**Relationships:**

**One post / comment** is always allocated to **one user**. I recommend you to have your own table for user, because you might want to expand the table in the future.

**One post** can have **multiple comments**. But **one comment** has only **one assigned post**.

You will also need to add [Foreign Keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp), to make sure the data stays consistent.